# "Path Not Found" when attempting to write to a sub folder within a mapped drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, path, mappeddrive, directory

We have an interesting issue with one of our server shares, or possibly, our Win 7  desktops.

When our users try to save files in a sub folder, either via copy/paste or through an application, to a mapped drive on our DC they receive an error saying "Path not found". They can however browse this folder and open files from it. This is where the "Path Not Found" error doesn't seem to stack up in my opinion.

Users can however save files fine in the root folder of the mapped drive, it appears only to affect sub folders.

It seems to be random which users and machines this affects. The users can log on to a different machine and be able to save in sub folders fine, on the same mapped drive. Event viewer hasn't been much help either.

Currently, the only solution we have found is to image the machines affected which solves the issue.

Our servers are Server 2008 R2 with Win 7 Pro desktops.

Any help/pointers/suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Dfs? Is the path in question possibly a Dfs link with more than one destination / replica?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We have had DFS enabled in the past, but it is now a disabled service. We haven't used DFS for sometime (perhaps 2 years), and this error has only just started happening.

Comment: How do you map the drives then? Do you have any fancy stuff like symlinks or junctions within your directory? Once the problem occurs with a certain workstation, is it persistent? Do you have any error messages regarding Kerberos authentication in your client or server / domain controller event logs?

Comment: @syneticon-dj. Thanks again for your reply. We use folder redirection to redirect the Documents folder, in addition to this, we also map a drive with a basic VBS script to their home folder.

Comment: Forgot to mention, we don't seem to have any errors that stand out in the error logs. Probably also worth mentioning, shortly before we started to have this problem the network connection was momentarily lost (cable knocked out) to the server where their folders are.

Answer (score 0):

Can your users you the UNC path to the sub-folder that they are having issues with? Are they then able to read and write data to these sub-folders? If so this indicates a permissions issue with a mapped drive itself.

Since you say they are able to read and write data to the root of the mapped drive I would ensure that your subfolders are Inheriting permissions from the root directory.

Comment: Yes, I believe they can use the UNC paths to the folders, though I will double check this.

I have just checked the folder permissions and they are definitely inheriting correctly, as they always seem to have.

Comment: @Adam Can you confirm that the users have both Security **AND** Share permissions?